# Custom managers django ... return super().get_queryset().filter(author=user)

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-managers

**How can I do something like this**

- models.py

```
class FilterManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet:
        user = self.request.user
        return super().get_queryset().filter(author=user)


FILTER1 = FilterManager()
```

- views.py

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.EventSerializer
    queryset = Event.FILTER1.all()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/managers/

The documentation and the Internet indicate that only static values of the form can be entered in the "filter" here:

```
 return super(PublishedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(active=True)
```

or

```
get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(city= 'kolkata')
```

**This is the right thing to do in models.py or is it better to do it in views.py ?**

I have a lot of repetitive code right now:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        try:
            queryset = Event.objects.filter(author=user)
            return queryset
        except:
            raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the right thing to do in models.py or is it better to do it in views.py ?

**No**, Django's model layer should be *request unaware*. Indeed, the idea is that models focus on creating, obtaining and aggregating data. Doing this in a useful way and presenting the data to the user is the task of the view layer.

A `Manager` has no request, so `self.request` when using a manager will fail, unless you somehow inject this, but that would make not much sense.

> I have a lot of repetitive code right now.

You can create a mixin for this. Indeed:

```
class MyAuthorViewMixin:
    author_field = 'author'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset()
            .filter(**{self.author_field: self.request.user})
        )
```

and then mix this into other views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class MyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, MyAuthorViewMixin, ListView):
    model = Event
```

so you write the logic to filter once, and then just mix it into other views.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin).

Comment: Ty very much for your answer ! 
But your mixing is not working for me.
ERROR: 
'MyViewSet' should either include a `queryset` attribute, or override the `get_queryset()` method.

Comment: What you think about this:
`return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)`    ?

Comment: $ django-admin --version
4.2.7

Comment: Name: djangorestframework
Version: 3.14.0

Comment: @AlexSidorov: for `APIView`s and `ViewSet`s, specifying a model is nout enough, you then specifiy the queryset as well, so `queryset = Event.objects.all()`

Comment: I need to add this to `queryset = Event.objects.all()` in views.py - ok, but, what you think about this:  `return self.model.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)` in mixin ?

Comment: @AlexSidorov: that's also fine, both are equivalent. The mixin in the answer can dit the author field, but that is not per se necessary.